# Upgraded from 2.8.x to 3.3.1 and lost content

Tags: upgrade, customization

First of all I did a manual upgrade of the wordpress site. I did everything by the book. I disabled all plugins, did all the backups.

I upgraded to the new version, everything went fine.

Only that I lost all content.

I switched from my custom themes to default one (Twenty Eleven 1.3) still my content seems to be gone.

On my php my admin page I SEE my content, they are not lost, just now shown.

Question, what do I need to do to make it appear?

I did upgrade the database during the install, it seems something went wrong.

Please help!

Thank you in advance!

EDIT1: I added errors after enabling debugging mode. The hungarian text reads:
the use of register_sidebar_widget is no longer supported since version 2.8. I beleive this error was there earlier, since I upgraded from version 2.9.x.

All help appriciated!

```
Notice: add_option was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.3 with no alternative available. in /mnt/buffer.1/srv/www/laszloerika.hu/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3553 
Notice: add_option was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.3 with no alternative available. in /mnt/buffer.1/srv/www/laszloerika.hu/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3553 
Notice: add_option was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.3 with no alternative available. in /mnt/buffer.1/srv/www/laszloerika.hu/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3553 
Notice: add_option was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.3 with no alternative available. in /mnt/buffer.1/srv/www/laszloerika.hu/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3553 Notice: register_sidebar_widget használata nem támogatott a 2.8 verzió óta! Ezt javasoljuk helyette: wp_register_sidebar_widget(). in /mnt/buffer.1/srv/www/laszloerika.hu/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3467
Notice: register_sidebar_widget használata nem támogatott a 2.8 verzió óta! Ezt javasoljuk helyette: wp_register_sidebar_widget(). in /mnt/buffer.1/srv/www/laszloerika.hu/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3467
Notice: register_sidebar_widget használata nem támogatott a 2.8 verzió óta! Ezt javasoljuk helyette: wp_register_sidebar_widget(). in /mnt/buffer.1/srv/www/laszloerika.hu/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3467
Notice: register_sidebar_widget használata nem támogatott a 2.8 verzió óta! Ezt javasoljuk helyette: wp_register_sidebar_widget(). in /mnt/buffer.1/srv/www/laszloerika.hu/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3467
Notice: register_widget_control használata nem támogatott a 2.8 verzió óta! Ezt javasoljuk helyette: wp_register_widget_control(). in /mnt/buffer.1/srv/www/laszloerika.hu/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3467
```

EDIT2:

I have this after switching to main theme. HOW do I disable widgets, I don't see any active one in the dashboard, I see widgets that can be used, but none active...

```
Notice: add_option was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.3 with no alternative available. in /mnt/buffer.1/srv/www/laszloerika.hu/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3553 Notice: add_option was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.3 with no alternative available. in /mnt/buffer.1/srv/www/laszloerika.hu/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3553     

Notice: add_option was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.3 with no alternative available. in /mnt/buffer.1/srv/www/laszloerika.hu/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3553 Notice: add_option was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.3 with no alternative available. in /mnt/buffer.1/srv/www/laszloerika.hu/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3553
Notice: register_sidebar_widget használata nem támogatott a 2.8 verzió óta! Ezt javasoljuk helyette: wp_register_sidebar_widget(). in /mnt/buffer.1/srv/www/laszloerika.hu/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3467
Notice: register_widget_control használata nem támogatott a 2.8 verzió óta! Ezt javasoljuk helyette: wp_register_widget_control(). in /mnt/buffer.1/srv/www/laszloerika.hu/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3467
```

-----------------Update 3---------------------

One of the plugins were sneaky and turned itself on. I switched it off, no errors.

BUT

NO CONTENT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! :(:( What now :D?

Comment: At this point, you need to work with a developer directly.  There isn't a way we can further diagnose the problem without actually seeing the admin side of things and looking very closely at your site and database.  That kind of work doesn't fit the format of this site ... I'll eventually close this as "Too Localized," but I'll keep it open for now to give you a chance to follow up with those who have left comments below.  I personally recommend moving this conversation to the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/stoppress) or to the [support forums](http://wordpress.org/support).

Comment: Well, he won't be able to chat since he doesn't have 20 reputation, so that's out.  If he can get it, I'll be happy to chat with him in a private room to bash this out.

Comment: I added this question to the support forums as well, no useful reply :( But thanks!

Comment: Please include a link to your forum thread so we can follow up there ...

Comment: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/upgrade-from-29x-to-latest-deleted-content?replies=1#post-2654808

Comment: Add an answer with your solution _(incremental upgrade)_ and mark the question as _answered_.

Comment: well, i voted thequestion up - dude now has 11 reputation, one more and he can take it to the chat room :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a guess, mind you, but it's still worth a shot.

First, turn on debug mode and see if there's any glaring errors when trying to view your content.  If not (and I'm thinking there won't be, but I would feel quite silly if there were errors pointing to the issue), then roll everything back to 2.8 (database and files)and manually upgrade to 3.0.x.  If your content is still there once that's done, back up your database again then upgrade to 3.3.x.

Edit:  At this point, it's either a theme issue or a plugin issue. The function `register_sidebar_widget` has been replaced with `wp_register_sidebar_widget`, and `register_widget_control` with `wp_register_widget_control`. First things first, switch to the default theme (Twenty Eleven). If your content shows up, we've narrowed it down to the theme, and you can just find/replace the former function with the latter.

If the theme's not the problem, then it's a plugin generating a specific widget.  Remove all your widgets and re-add them one by one.  Whichever plugin generates the widget causing the failure is the offending plugin, and can be updated or replaced.

Comment: Ah, now we're getting somewhere!  At this point, it's either a theme issue or a plugin issue.  The function register_sidebar_widget has been replaced with wp_register_sidebar_widget.  First things first, switch to the default theme. If your content shows up, we've narrowed it down to the theme, and you can just find/replace the former function with the latter.  If it's not the theme, then make sure your plugins are compatible with 3.x - if one isn't, chances are the function is in there.  Once that function's fixed we'll see if anything else is going on.

Comment: Ensure you're using the Twenty Eleven Theme. Disable **all** Plugins. Remove **all** Widgets. Then, if your content still doesn't appear, report back with any **Fatal Error** PHP notices. Also: do you have a URL for the site in question?

Comment: the website in question is: http://www.laszloerika.hu/wordpress

Comment: Updated main post. Still not working...

Comment: At this point, go with Chip's advice - switch to Twenty Eleven and disable all plugins, then re-enable them one by one.  If there's still no content with all plugins disabled, let us know - there's a zlib compression error being thrown currently that may point to an issue with the host itself if the plugins aren't at fault.

Comment: I updated main question. I disabled all plugins, switched to main theme I have no fatal error. No content either :( The content is there according to Dashboard, just not on the blog itself :(

Comment: Did you **disable all Plugins**? Something is screwy here. Your index page is displaying `comment_form()` content, and you're getting *all* of these body classes: `home page page-id-37 page-template-default single-author two-column right-sidebar` - which makes NO sense to me.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to have you try something different just in case.  In wp-config.php, add the following line somewhere before `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');`

`@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'off');`

Also, are there still errors being thrown?

Comment: Had another thought - move all the plugin folders out of the plugins directory to make sure none are somehow re-enabling themselves.  You can just delete them all and upload one by one if necessary.

Comment: Sir yes sir Mr. Bennett, I may be wrong. @SickHippie removing plugin folder as whole!

Comment: @GergelyCsata - well, it does ensure there's no chance of any of them being loaded! :)

Comment: @SickHippie I did as u asked - both - removed plugin folder and added the ini... nothing happened!

Comment: Well, then I'm going to suggest what I did initially - roll back to 2.8 (database and files), switch to default theme, disable all plugins disable all widgets, and incrementally update instead of going straight to 3.3.  See this thread for more details.  http://wordpress.org/support/topic/upgrade-from-261-to-33?replies=3 - we may be chasing our tails when the issues is just an improper database upgrade.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will rollback database then, everything else as well, then do incremental upgrades.

Comment: troubleshooting step:
if you enter new post,now page does it show up ?